# Timer callback in Pharo smalltalk + Seaside

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I've just ported my Dolphin Smalltalk + Seaside application to the latest Pharo Smalltalk 4.0 and Seaside 3.1. In it, I need a callback every second from the (browser) client to the (Pharo) server to update the view.

I had this piece of code to press the "Update"  button automatically every second. But it does not work anymore after the port to Pharo:

```
html script: (
    ( html jQuery: '#updateButton' ) 
        call: 'click';
        interval: 1000 ).
```

I've searched the net for other (more elegant?) solutions but can't seem to get them to work. Can anybody give me a hint on how to proceed?

This is the JavaScript code that is generated by the code above and which used to work in Dolphin + Seaside:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
<![CDATA[/setInterval(function(){$("#updateButton").cl‌​ick()},2000)/]]>
*/</script>
```

Comment: Can you share why 'it does not work' ? Do you get an error in the browser or on the server?

Comment: @Johan: the error is that the callback is never called after the timeout. I tested this by writing someting to the Transcript window in the onUpdate method. When I press the update button, coupled to the same callback, the Transcript text appears.

Comment: @Euan M 22: Yes you van mail me about the porting experence. (But is it a very small app)

Comment: BTW: This is the Javascript that is generated be the code above and used to work in Dolphin + Seaside: <script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/setInterval(function(){$("#updateButton").click()},2000)/*]]>*/</script>   .... Seems OK.

Comment: Which release and version of Pharo are you using?

Comment: @FP I can't reply to the email address you mailed from.  :-(  Is there a problem with your email provider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that the server callback is attached to the button with id `#updateButton`? It is odd that you have a script that triggers a click action on that button instead of triggering a callback every xx seconds.

The following script would update the entire body every 10 seconds. Given that you implement the right rendering methods, this is probably a more elegant solution:

```
html script: (
    ((html jQuery: 'body') load
        html: [ :innerHtml | self renderOn: innerHtml ]) 
            interval: 10000)
```

Comment: Hi @Johan B, that looks like the right direction, but gives the error message:
    MessageNotUnderstood: JQueryInstance>>load:
There is indeed no "load:" method implemented in JQueryInstance or its superclasses.

Comment: And PS: I want to update the entire view. Not just one element.

Comment: @FunctionPoint I adapted the code snippet to fix my error (I should have evaluated it in a workspace before posting, sorry about that). Next, I also changed the jQuery expression to select the 'body' instead of an element with id #content, but this is something I cannot derive from your original code post.

Comment: Hi Johan, I tried your script but nothing happens. Also tried "renderContentOn: iso renderOn:. Below is the Javascript that is renerated. I'm using Pharo 4.0 downloaded nov 28 and imported SeaSide 3.1 into the image with a Metacello script the same day.  <script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/setInterval(function(){$("body").load("http://localhost:8080/WAMyApp",["_s=rKlYttZNpVV9sFf6","_k=daUQjT9IHkU0hlQN","2"].join("&"))},3000)/*]]>*/</script>

Comment: I set a "self halt" in the render method to catch all occurences, but it only gets hit when I manually press the update button coupled to it.

Comment: Are there calls made from the browser to the server? Are you sure jQuery is loaded in the browser? Is there any error appearing in the browser dev tools console?

Comment: F*kin-A, Johan! :-)) Indeed, I got an error message every <callback timeout> seconds in the browser, compaining that "$" was undefined. Further inspection showed that the lines for including JQuery libraries were not generated in the HTML. I needed to include them using in the Seaside configuration tool again. Now it is working again, and better, with your improved script for rendering the body HTML (iso my previous automatically pressing the Update button.). Thank you so much!!